# Which sovereign states currently have nuclear power stations but no nuclear weapons programs?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, nuclear-energy

Put another way, which sovereign states besides the following have nuclear power stations?

- China
- France
- India
- Israel
- North Korea
- Pakistan
- Russia
- United Kingdom
- United States

Comment: Iran, Germany, Sweden, Japan at least. For Europe there's a list of nuclear power plant 'owning' countries here: http://www.euronuclear.org/info/encyclopedia/n/nuclear-power-plant-europe.htm

Comment: Thanks! If you expand this into a full answer, with sources, then I'll gladly mark it as "accepted" :)

Comment: Any particular reason the Wikipedia page doesn't satisfy you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_stations

Comment: @DVK, the list on the page you linked to is incomplete. The answer to my question may be "Wikiable" (I don't know whether it is or not), but if so, then it seems only to be non-trivially so.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to remove "but no nuclear weapons programs".

Comment: @SVilcans why would I want to do that, given that the question I asked is the one to which I sought the answer?

Comment: @sampablokuper Because your initial list contains several countries that have nuclear weapons, i.e. US, Russia, UK, France, China and Israel (unofficial).

Comment: @SVilcans, that is because the list in my *question* is intended to be mutually exclusive with the list in a correct *answer*. This is explained by my use of the word "besides" in my question.

Comment: @user45891 - I do not buy that Iran and Germany do not have a NW program.  I would not be surprised to find out Japan had one of its own.

Comment: @Chad the closest we could get is a list of countries that state that they don't have NW programs (ie NPT treaty signatories).

Comment: @Chad Let's start with Iran. Why does it want nuclear weapons - mainly as deterrent against Israel. And it doesn't make sense to hide your doomsday device (And every intelligence community agrees that they currently aren't actively developing http://intelnews.org/2012/03/19/01-950/ ). For Germany we basically have nuclear weapons because the US is storing some in Germany (Nuclear sharing, which might also explain the lack of a japanese program) - though we do have some HEU (http://www.fissilematerials.org/blog/2010/11/germany_declared_its_2009.html)

Comment: @user45891 - I dont care why someone may want them they have them.  And not every intelligence agency agrees on anything.  Every intelligence agency agreed that Saddam had weapons... right up until we didnt find any then they all came out and said yeah we knew that.

Comment: @Chad Actually no, Curveball and the other chap's information was deemed questionable (http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-21786506), the US & UK however chose to ignore that. But, I grant you that there probably are intelligence agencies that question the state of the nuclear program in Iran (Probably the dutch; You never heard of them? Well that's how good they are) - still there is no doubt that the US and Israel are at the top of their game and HIGHLY critical of Iran (They just increased sanctions even though talks have progressed) - so, even though it is hard, maybe sometimes we can trust them

Comment: @user45891 - The only thing you can trust the US to do is what is in the best interest of the person in charge at the time the action is taken.  And while the intel was questionable all the major players agreed it was probably correct... until they found out it wasnt.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that the atomic weapons programs and the nuclear power programs of the world, for the most part were **entirely separate**. Sweden tried to combine the two, [failed miserably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R4_nuclear_reactor) and the reactor is somewhat of a laughing stock, even in Sweden. The UK ran [a few reactors in both military and civilian fuel cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnox) but for the most part used dedicated breeders for weapons. The Soviet RBMK's could be used for weapons. [But alas...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster)

Comment: It is worth noting that Israel and North Korea do not have nuclear power plants, and that Australia will imminently have nuclear powered submarines but neither nuclear weapons nor nuclear power plants. https://aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/14/why-australia-wants-nuclear-powered-submarines

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the "horses mouth" so to speak, [the IAEA](https://www.iaea.org/PRIS/WorldStatistics/OperationalReactorsByCountry.aspx). Note that Iran is suspected of having a program, but no conclusive evidence is publicly available. This list also includes those with [sharing programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_sharing).

| Country | Number of Reactors | Total Net Capacity (MW) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 3 | 1627 |
| Armenia | 1 | 375 |
| Belgium | 7 | 5927 |
| Brazil | 2 | 1884 |
| Bulgaria | 2 | 1906 |
| Canada | 19 | 13500 |
| Czech Republic | 6 | 3884 |
| Finland | 4 | 2752 |
| Germany | 9 | 12068 |
| Hungary | 4 | 1889 |
| Iran | 1 | 915 |
| Japan | 48 | 42388 |
| South Korea | 23 | 20721 |
| Mexico | 2 | 1330 |
| Netherlands | 1 | 482 |
| Romania | 2 | 1300 |
| Slovakia | 4 | 1815 |
| Slovenia | 1 | 688 |
| South Africa | 2 | 1860 |
| Spain | 7 | 7121 |
| Sweden | 10 | 9474 |
| Switzerland | 5 | 3308 |
| Taiwan | 6 | 5032 |
| Ukraine | 15 | 13107 |

Comment: Thanks! [The page you linked](http://www.iaea.org/PRIS/WorldStatistics/OperationalReactorsByCountry.aspx) says "The following information is included in the totals", and then links to [this page about Taiwan](http://www.iaea.org/PRIS/CountryStatistics/CountryDetails.aspx?current=TW), which lists six operational reactors and two more under construction, so I've edited your answer to include Taiwan.